# Компьютерные сети

Tags: сеть, lan, передача-данных

есть у меня такая проблема не могу настроить маршрутизацию между узлами задание было такое: Требуется связать локальной сетью, компьютеры расположенные на  первом этаже здания №1 и компьютеры, установленные на втором этаже здания №2. Связь внутри зданий осуществить на основе стандарта IEEE 802.3 (Ethernet), а объединение подсетей зданий должно быть реализовано с помощью оптоволоконной линии связи. Серверная комната находится в комнате №103 здания №1
будет рассмотрена локальная вычислительная сеть, объединяющая в себе 2 подсети, находящиеся в разных зданиях, схематически показана модель построения этой сети, а также будет произведено назначение IP — адресов узлам и маршрутизатору, выбор магистрального канала передачи данных и подсчёт финансовых расходов на реализацию этого проекта.

вот как то так что я делаю неправильно(((????

[image: первая картинка]

[image: вторая]

[image: третья]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Хочу настроить vlan и trunk port чтобы с другого vlan можно отправить любому и получить

Comment: Давайте сначала сверимся. Очевидно ли для вас, что для пересылки данных между двумя разными IP-сетями (неважно, в разные они коммутаторы воткнуты или в разные VLAN'ы на одном коммутаторе) необходим маршрутизатор, у которого есть интерфейс в каждой из этих сетей?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev от автора : Хочу настроить vlan и trunk port чтобы с другого vlan можно отправить любому и получить